# Call a script from more than one button?

Tags: javascript

I have a need to add 3 buttons to call the same javascript form, when I add more than one instance of the link, they all seem to fail except for the first instance. Is this possible?

```
<a class="button" href="" id="eventButton">Find out more</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gatherhere.com/js/leadform.js" id="gather-loader" data-locationid="7ppyugvm" data-trigger="eventButton"></script>
```

Comment: How exactly are we supposed to help you here?

Answer (score 1):

You only need one `<script>` tag per script, remember that `id`s on an element are unique, and therefore multiple buttons with the same ID will invalidate your markup, meaning only the first button will have the action assigned to it.

If you want 2 buttons to share the same action in Javascript, consider using a `class` instead of an `ID`

Comment: If this helped you, consider up voting it or marking it as the answer for future SO users.  Thanks

Comment: Dont worry, earn rep by accepting answers, answering questions and asking good questions :)